# How to overwrite DropzoneJS's XHR for GridFS?

Tags: javascript, meteor, dropzone.js, gridfs, collectionfs

I'm currently developping an image sharing plateform, using Meteor, CollectionFS and GridFS StorageAdapter.

I'm also using the excellent package [dbarrett:dropzonejs](https://atmospherejs.com/dbarrett/dropzonejs), but problem is its implementation for CollectionFS, especially regarding XHR and uploadprogress stuff.

For now, i use [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31715544/dropzone-file-not-fully-processed-when-calling-processfilefile).

**Problem** : when uploading files, i noticed in console unwanted POST requests
alongside PUT requests from CollectionFS.
I narrowed them down to xhr.send() in dbarrett_dropzone.js file.
In attempt to stop them, i tried in template.rendered > dropzone options :

```
init: function() {
    this.on("sending", function(file,xhr) {
        xhr.abort(); //file.xhr.abort() does not work either...
    });
} // console shows "NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED"
```

or overwriting dropzone.accept :

```
},
accept: function(file,done) {
    done("dummy message");
},
```

but then it prevents Queue array to be populated, which is needed for CollectionFS inserts...

**Question**: i think needs to overwrite dropzone.uploadFiles(files) function, where all the xhr stuff is written,
... but all my attempts failed, can someone propose an implementation please ?

Ideally, i'm thinking such implementation would be like this :

```
Template.albumContent.rendered = function() {
    var dz = new Dropzone("form#dzId", {
        url: "#",
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        acceptedFiles: "image/*",
        init: function() {
            this.on("success", function(file) {
                Meteor.setTimeout(function() {
                    dz.removeFile(file);
                },3000)
            });
        },
        uploadFiles: function(files) {
            var dzgqf = dz.getQueuedFiles();
            if (dzgqf.length) {
                dzgqf.forEach(function(file) {
                    var fsFile = new FS.File(file);
                    fsFile.owner = Meteor.userId();
                    Images.insert(fsFile, function(error, fileObj) {
                        if (error) throw new Meteor.Error("Error uploading this file : ", fsFile);
                        // how to pass properly fileObj.updateProgress() stuff to dz.uploadprogress event ???
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    });
}

Template.albumContent.events({
    "click .js-upload-all-images": function(event, template) {
        event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation();
        var dz = Dropzone.getElement("#dzId").dropzone;
        console.log("Queued files : ", dz.getQueuedFiles());
        dz.processQueue();
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

After testing many work-arounds,  i ended up with the working solution below :

```
Template.albumContent.rendered = function() {
    var dz = new Dropzone("form#dzId", {
        url: "#",
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        acceptedFiles: "image/*",
        maxFilesize: 10,
        init: function() {
            this.on("success", function(file) {
                dz.removeFile(file);
            });
            this.on("queuecomplete", function() {
                dz.removeAllFiles(); // removes remaining rejected files
            });
        }
    });
}

Template.albumContent.events({
    "click .js-upload-all-images": function(event, template) {
        event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation();
        var dz = Dropzone.getElement("#dzId").dropzone,
            dzgqf = dz.getQueuedFiles();
        console.log("Queued files : ", dzgqf);

        if (dzgqf.length) {
            dzgqf.forEach(function(file) {
                var fsFile = new FS.File(file);
                fsFile.owner = Meteor.userId();
                fsFile.metadata = {
                    name: file.name
                };
                Images.insert(fsFile, function(error, fileObj) {
                    if (error) throw new Meteor.Error("Error uploading this file : ", fsFile);
                    Tracker.autorun( function() {
                        var fO = Images.findOne(fileObj._id);
                        if (fO.uploadProgress() !== 100) {
                            console.log(f0.metadata.name + ": chunk " + f0.chunkCount+"/"+fO.chunkSum + " - Progress " + fO.uploadProgress()+"%");
                            dz.emit("uploadprogress", file, fO.uploadProgress());
                        }
                        else {// if (fileObj.hasStored("mediasStore") {
                            console.log("File " + f0.metadata.name + " were successfully stored in FScollection 'Images'");
                            dz.emit(complete, file) // removes file's progressbar
                              .emit("success" file); // shows the checkmark then auto slides it out
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        }
     }
});
```

Not really compliant with how DropzoneJS events expects, but at least progress displays are working, without xhr POSTs firing.

bugs: "_ref.parentNode" not found, from "removedFile" event

If anyone has a cleaner implementation, feel free to post !

If enyo read this, it would be nice to correct my example, and why not share it in DropzoneJS main page.
Same for dbarrett in Atmosphere package page.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to send an image using DropzoneJs and GridFS. [ProcessImage](https://github.com/ccorcos/meteor-clientside-image-manipulation) is used to resize the image on the client side first before sending it to the server.

```
Template.imageUpload.rendered = function() {
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    var dropzone = new Dropzone("form#dropzone", {
        acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
        accept: function(file, done) {

            processImage(file, 1024, 1024, function(data) {
                var img = new FS.File(data);
                img.owner = Meteor.userId();
                img.metadata = {
                    sourceId: Session.get('conditionUniqueId'),
                    staged: true
                };

                Images.insert(img, function(err, fileObj) {
                    if (err) {
                        return console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        dropzone.emit("complete", file).emit("success", file);
                    }
                });
            })

            done();
        }

    });
}
```